# How to find comments

Tags: support, comments

On main profile there answers and questions . How to find our comments? Is there any way find out which question we commented on them?

Comment: This what you are looking for? http://askubuntu.com/users/181205/alex?tab=activity&sort=comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all your recent comments (in order of newest to oldest) [on your profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/181205/alex?tab=activity&sort=comments).

[image]

You can also get a list of replies to your comments/answers/etc under the "Responses" tab.